# Spotfire Dropdown filter won't work for a calculated column

Tags: dropdown, spotfire

I've got a `spotfire` tool that works with action control dropdowns.

I've added a calculated column in order to rename some of the metrics currently in the table.

When I choose the dropdowns to filter my table based on the calculated column it returns me an empty table?

Any thoughts?

Here's my data sample

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot with some sample data?

Comment: So I want to replace the column "Reserves" shown here with my calculated column to be used in the drop=down.

Comment: @Mourst- Did you link this property control to your table?

Answer (score 1):

@Mourst - Here is how you can link your property control to your table.

After you add your calculated column to your table and created a property control, right click on the table and go to **Data** > **Limit data using expression**.

Add an expression which filters table values based on the property control selection value.

**Example below:**

In this case, filtered table will show rows whose [calc_x] is less than or equal to property control value.

```
[calc_x]<=DocumentProperty("mycalc")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where you have "mycalc" should I be using the name from the Document properties tab? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm still can't make it to work. Forgot to mention that my calculated column is string. Does equals works in this case? This is the expression I am using : [Reserves PRMS]=DocumentProperty("PRMS")

Comment: Could you post sample data table? That will give a clear picture as where the issue is.

Comment: @Mourst- Post sample data in your question itself.

Comment: sorry new to stackoverflow.Added it in my question

Comment: @Mourst- No problem. what values does document property contain?

Comment: @Mourst- Instead of = try using ~= in the expression [Reserves PRMS]=DocumentProperty("PRMS") which means if the column contains property value selected, table is filtered if the value matches.

Comment: Hi. The document property contains string values. My issue is that I want drop down 1 to slice the data based on value 1 and the drop down 2 to do the same for value 2. Will that require 2 different document property controls and 2 different expressions?Thanks

Comment: @Mourst - Can you provide some sample values in drop down 1 and 2.  Also, sample values in the column that it is trying to filter? Based on the values, we can design a solution that suits your requirement.

Comment: Sample values for both drop downs are :"Economically Viable, Not Viable,Reserves". Same are the values for the column I am trying to filter by.

Comment: The column values in the tables shows 'Reserves and economically viable'. In that case, when you select 'Reserves' or 'Economically Viable' from drop down, all those rows with column value that contains these strings should filter?

Comment: The column values in the table include the samples I've commented above plus what you comment here. So in total I have 5 different values and combinations. (Reserves+economically viable, not viable+reserves etc).Non e of them filters even the ones that are identical match. I just get an empty table when I use the dropdowns

Comment: Have you tried using ~= instead of = in custom expression? Example: [calc_x] ~= DocumentProperty("mycalc"). As you are applying filters on a text column, ~= should help.

Comment: Yeah used that but still not working...The thing is driving me crazy!

Comment: Manage to work around it. I did calculate and replace in the old document property and basically just renamed it to what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I switch the column to the calculated one it simply won't work and won't filter the data. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21VZi.png)

Comment: @Mourst- Edit your question and add this screenshot there.